# struts 2 Undefined attribute name "var"

Tags: struts2

I am trying to iterate over two 2D arrays `Org_Positions_IdTitle` and `Org_Apps` and print out a field but I keep getting the `Attribute var invalid for tag iterator according to TLD` also in my jsp page the var1 and var2 are underlined and it says on the left Undefined attribute name "var".
I would be so thankful if you can help me with that.

```
    <s:iterator value="Org_Positions_IdTitle" var="arr1" >
        <s:iterator value="Org_Apps" var="arr2" >
            <s:if test="#arr1[0] == #arr2[1] ">
                <s:property value="#arr1[1]" />     
            </s:if>
        </s:iterator>
    </s:iterator>
```

Comment: As I told you in your previous question. The `id` attribute is deprecated long time ago. So if you are using very old version of Struts2 then use it, otherwise use `var`.

Comment: Thanks a lot I used the Id and it worke out. Once again thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Struts 2 do you use?

If your version less then 2.1.x you should use `id` attribute, according to documentation: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/iterator.html