# Struts2 jsp error invalid attribute

Tags: jsp, struts2, jsp-tags, tld

my jsp file is:

```
<!html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>......some other code and then :::::
<li><s:url action="menuAction.action" var="fill" />
<s:a href="%{fill}">Fill Survey Form</s:a>
```

my other list items should also get redirected to same action class

The exception which I get is :

> 16:36:51,966 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SWE645_struts].[jsp]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /web/tilesLayout/Menu.jsp(48,11) Attribute var invalid for tag url according to TLD
>           at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]

Comment: The answer is in the message: `Attribute var invalid for tag url according to TLD`. So, you need to check your tld file.

Comment: Which S2 version? Try `id` instead of `var`.

Comment: Or better, try the latest version ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [struts 2 Undefined attribute name "var"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148672/struts-2-undefined-attribute-name-var)